# Get no. of rows returned by stored procedure in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have created a report using SQL Server Reporting Services that makes use of a stored procedure. I added the stored procedure as a Dataset for the report and its making use of parameters to do some filtering etc.

This all works perfectly, but I want to display the no. of rows that were returned by the stored procedure at the bottom of the report. In attempt to do this I added an output parameter to my stored procedure and i have this statement after the `SELECT` statement:

```
SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT
```

This parameter appears in my parameter list in Visual Studio and I added it to my report, but its value is always 0.

[image: Mars report parameters]

[image: Mars report count output]

What I'm wondering is how am I supposed to catch the output parameter in my report, or is there some other way to get this count in my report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to directly catch output parameters of Stored Procedures using Reporting Services.

The easiest way to get the number of records in the returned dataset, is simply to use an expression in the textbox where you want to show the count:

```
=CountRows("stp_CityHealthResearchRequests")
```

If you want to filter your count, use the Sum-function together with the Iif-function. For example, if you only want to count the number of records where the Concluded-column has the value "Yes":

```
=Sum(Iif(Fields!Concluded.Value = "Yes",1,0),"stp_CityHealthResearchRequests")
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, that's perfect